# Lights and shadows in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, light

So, I'm making a game with Unity, and I have to cover other parts of the level with a shadow, so that the player can't see them. [This is how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xscEe.png) the game looks like now, and more or less i'd like it to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtfmU.png)

Someone nows how to help me? Like with some tutorials or tips.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Normally this sounds like what the world calls “fog of war”.

Answer (score 0):

One solution it would be to cover the part of the level with an object, and you may remove it by using a collider to detect if player is near or maybe by player position

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I'd like it to fade, not just remove a big chunk of it.